# int:transformer expression error- The value of attribute "expression" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using spring integration in my project. I want to append  `<response>` and `</response>` as strings to my payload before and after respectively. I am using `int:transformer` to do this. The following is the piece of code:

```
<int:transformer    expression="'<response>' + payload + '</response>'"/>
```

But when I use the above expression, I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "expression" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 58 more
```

Can anybody tell me how my `expression` should be to accomplish my task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
<int:transformer expression="'&lt;response>' + payload + '&lt;/response>'"/>
```

Since you define string literal with XML in the XML you should escape those symbols which represent XML language per se.

Comment: That's perfect..+1 for explanation.